# How to compile and install a 32Bit library on a 64 Bit (Ubuntu 12.04LTS) Linux using autotools, make and gcc?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc, makefile, autotools

I'm trying to compile a 32Bit version of a linux library on a 64Bit Ubuntu 12.04LTS running inside a VM (VirtualBox).

So far I've downloaded the source, unzipped it and performed the following steps to build the lib:

```
libtoolize --force
automake --add-missing
./configure --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu "CFLAGS=-m32" "CXXFLAGS=-m32" "LDFLAGS=-m32"
make
sudo make install
```

With this I've been able to build an compile the library but, once I run "readelf -h" on the compiled lib I get the following output:

```
  ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
  Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x1ac0
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          53904 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         7
  Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         35
  Section header string table index: 32
```

So I'm stuck with a 64Bit Version of the library and have not yet found a way to force the build and installation of a 32Bit Version. I'd be grateful for hints on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only set `--build` in your options for `./configure`.  That means that `./configure` should behave as if the program is being compiled on a 32-bit computer.  If you want it to run on a 32-bit computer as well, you should use `--host=i386-linux-gnu`.  So the real configure command you want to run is:

```
./configure --build=i386-linux-gnu --host=i386-linux-gnu
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint random, the command you provided didn't do the trick but brought me on the right track. config.guess outputs "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu" in the VM and again results in a 64 bit lib. skipping the CF, CXX, LD Flags results in linker errors. So the correct comman that produced the 32 Bit lib was: ./configure --build=`i386-linux-gnu` --host=i386-linux-gnu "CFLAGS=-m32" "CXXFLAGS=-m32" "LDFLAGS=-m32" If you edit your post accordingly I'll mark it as correct answer.

Comment: @norritt Well, I guess that answers the conundrum.  Well done on finding out the answer for yourself!